# Convert float to nearest number ending with .5

Tags: python

How can I convert

```
1.0 -> 0.95
0.91 -> 0.95
0.9 -> 0.85
```

etc.

I'm doing a histogram of values in the range of 0 (exclusive) and 1 (inclusive).

Comment: why does 1.0 go down to 0.95, rather than up to 1.05? While 0.9 goes down to 0.85 and not up to 0.95?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/133242)

Comment: Hint: rounding a number to the nearest 1/20th is the same as rounding the 20 times larger number to the nearest integer, then dividing by 20.

Comment: wouldn't `0.995` be nearer to `1.0` then `0.95`? I don't see the pattern here.

Comment: @Amadan: true, but he's not rounding to the nearest 1/20th -- otherwise 1 would stay as 1. He's rounding to _every other_ 1/20th.

Comment: @katrielalex: Oh, right. Well the basic principle still holds :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're doing a histogram, you don't round the numbers. You define a bunch of bins and count the number of points in each bin.

You can write code to do this yourself, or just use [`numpy.histogram`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html#numpy.histogram).